# Why we can edit view in sql server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

In sql server we can Update data view.I think the concept of view is a **read only table**.
Why we can edit view in sql.is there possible in oracle?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "update view"? Run an `UPDATE` statement against a view? Yes that's possible in Oracle as well (and in many other modern DBMS)

Comment: Update data.why we can update view?

Comment: Don't you need "Instead of" triggers on the View to perform the update logic?

Comment: I think we can update a view's data until it belongs to a single table, we can't run update if view is consists of select query from multiple tables using joins

Comment: @yogi, not exactly ([create view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), see Updatable Views sections), but yes, there are some limitations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question of why can we create an editable view, it is so that you can limit access to fields that you do not want updated (or viewed). Then you can give a user access to the view, but not to the underlying tables

For a simple example, you could have a personnel table. You could create an view allowing some users to update a field like emergency contact details, but not see or update bank details or salary

There are lots of criteria to meet to make a view updatable,  and you can indeed use INSTEAD OF triggers for extended functionality http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> I think the concept of view is a read only table

No, it's more of a *virtual* table - anywhere you have a real table, you ought to be able to replace it with a view, and the users should be none the wiser.

According to [Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules):

> Rule 6: The view updating rule:
>   All views that are theoretically updatable must be updatable by the system.

However, in practicality, this ideal has not been achievable.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @JamieA wrote, views can not only limit access to fields, but also limit access to data in the table.
Look at simple [SQL-Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80d36/1) and experiment with it.

The view in the example restrict access only to columns id,val1 of the table, but also restrics access to rows (only id = 2..10). You can update and delete only rows 2..10 throught the view. 
However the view does not prevent insertion of a row with id = 20
Here is [another example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/465a8/1) - a *view with check option* - it this case the view prevents not only deletes and updates, but prevent also inserting rows that do not match a where clause of the view.
@yogi wrote that we can't update a view if the view joins two tables -> here is a [third demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/429ca/1) that shows a simple view that joins two tables, and how an update  of this view works.
These simple examples are for Oracle, but after small modifications should also work in MS-SQL (must change datatypes in create tables), since when i looked througs MSDN documentation (section: updatable views -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), I didn't find any significant differences between ms-sql and oracle, it seems that views work similary on both databases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in Oracle, the other answers already explained why views are updatable and had shed some light on that question, they are also allowed in Oracle but have some restrictions/limitations here is the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html)

Like, the view select cant have: aggregate functions, distinct clause, group by... read the link for more info

Answer (score -2):

Since views are `read only tables` and its `doesn't support DML statements` you can't perform update on view.

An interesting factor is there you can write `update statemnt over view` and write a `instead of trigger` for that hence you can perform `multiple update statements` on tables which are in the view.

According to [Pinal Dev](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/03/sql-server-the-limitations-of-the-views-eleven-and-more/) Views having following limitations

- ORDER BY Does Not Work.
- Adding Column is Expensive by Joining Table Outside View
- Index Created on View not Used Often
- SELECT * and Adding Column Issue in View
- COUNT(*) Not Allowed but COUNT_BIG(*) Allowed
- UNION Not Allowed but OR Allowed in Index View
- Cross Database Queries Not Allowed in Indexed View
- Outer Join Not Allowed in Indexed Views
- SELF JOIN Not Allowed in Indexed View
- Keywords View Definition Must Not Contain for Indexed View
- View Over the View Not Possible with Index View

Comment: This is about indexed views. Also, Pinal Dave is not the best source on the web. He is just regurgitating information from the official documentation.

Comment: Views are not 'read only tables', in many cases (if the view meets some basic conditions - even when joining two or more tables) you can modify a table under the view without the instead of trigger , see documentation for details , section "updatable views": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx